# Mendeley Harvard reference format

Tags: citations, citation-style, formatting, reference-managers

Does anyone know where I can find a correct Harvard reference format to upload on Mendeley Desktop and use it with the Mendeley Word plug-in?

It seems that the ones available are not correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Zotero Style Repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles) and [search for the term "harvard"](https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=harvard).

You can preview a style by hovering over its name:

[image]

Once you've found your style, right click on the "Source" link and click on "Copy Link Address". (e.g. https://www.zotero.org/styles/harvard-cite-them-right?source=1)

[image]

Now in Mendeley, go to "View > Citation Style > More Styles... > Get More Styles" and copy/paste the link in the "Download Style" box (and click "Download")

[image]

Then go back to the "Installed" tab and select the style you just downloaded and click "Use this Style":

[image]

*(You may have to restart MS Word)*